Trying to read R plot prp tree

I dont understand how to read each leaf in my tree.
There is one big number on the top and then 6 on the bottem. what do they mean?
Here is the main part of my code:
fit<- rpart(Quality.of.Sleep~., method= "class", data=df , control=rpart.control(minsplit = 1))
prp(fit,extra = 1)

Trying to understand each leaf

Take bubble 4, (5,1,1,0,0,0).  It looks like '4' is a type of class whose members (observations 5+1+1 = 7) have stress >=7, have some occupation and blood pressure. It is unclear from the tree which combination of occupation and blood pressure results in class '4', though might be revealed via summary(fit). The string of numbers in each bubble add up to your 374 observations. Welcome to Stackoverflow.
